# How to assign levels to a column based on specific dates and levels in another column?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have an example dataset with 3 columns: JulianDay, Device, and location. See code below.

```
structure(list(JulianDay = 40:69, Device = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), Location = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Looking through the data, you can see that Device a is at location 1 on days 40, 43, 46. However the devices change locations, and location 1 is occupied by device b on days 49, 52, 55 and device c on 61, 64, 67. Similar changes happen for all three devices.

Now imagine that we only have the first two columns, but I know each date that a Device changes locations and which location it goes to. How could I reconstruct column 3 with that information. Obviously with 30 rows, it would be easy to just manually input, but I'm dealing with a real dataframe that has a few hundred thousand rows.

EDIT:

```
structure(list(JulianDay = c(40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 
42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45), Device = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Location = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Here's a similar dataframe that might clear up the question. Each device is active on every day and on every day there are 3 locations. Without the physical Location column (but knowing what should be contained within) I would like to code something like the following:

```
if(JulianDay < 41 & Device == 'A') { Location == 1}
if(JulianDay > 41 * JulianDay < 44 & Device == 'A') { Location == 3}
if(JulianDay > 44 & Device == 'A') {Location == 2
```

Such that a third column (Location) is filled out.

Comment: This question was unclear to me. Do you mean that a particular day is always tied to a particular location? E.g., if 40 is 1, then 41 is 2, 42 is 3, and 43 is 1, and so on.

Comment: @MikaelPoulJohannesson Just edited the post. Hopefully this clears up confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a set of conditional expectations based on `JulianDay` and `Device` that need to be executed in turn to create `Location`, then you should take look at `dplyr::case_when`.

From the docs (see `?dplyr::case_when`):

> This function allows you to vectorise multiple ‘if_else()’ statements.
>   It is an R equivalent of the SQL ‘CASE WHEN’ statement. If no cases
>   match, ‘NA’ is returned.

For instance, with your example,

```
data <- structure(list(JulianDay = c(40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 
42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45), Device = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Location = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

library(dplyr)

data$Location <- case_when(
  data$JulianDay < 41 & data$Device == "a" ~ 1,
  data$JulianDay > 41 & data$JulianDay < 44 & data$Device == "a" ~ 3,
  data$JulianDay > 44 & data$Device == "a" ~ 2
)
```